# How to solve this fail during installation of Pillow?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install pillow and can't solve this installation error.

Python version 3.9.7.

Pip version 22.1.2

Thank you for help.

`PS C:\code\django> python -m pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
Using cached Pillow-9.1.1.tar.gz (49.8 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error`

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [186 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39
creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_binary.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_util.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_*init*_.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_*main*_.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
running egg_info
writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.c'
warning: no files found matching '*.h'
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

```
  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
 
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\MarosPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ehd7ptp\pillow_96d0524dfca7421cb23061be6a1a17a3\setup.py", line 989, in
```

setup(
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 136, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\MarosPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ehd7ptp\pillow_96d0524dfca7421cb23061be6a1a17a3\setup.py", line 804, in 
build_extensions
          raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
     
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "", line 2, in 
        File "", line 34, in 
        File "C:\Users\MarosPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ehd7ptp\pillow_96d0524dfca7421cb23061be6a1a17a3\setup.py", line 1009, in 
          raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
     
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
     
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
     
     
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for Pillow did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [190 lines of output]
running install
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39
creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_binary.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_util.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_*init*_.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
copying src\PIL_*main*_.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-39\PIL
running egg_info
writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.c'
warning: no files found matching '*.h'
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

```
  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
 
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\MarosPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ehd7ptp\pillow_96d0524dfca7421cb23061be6a1a17a3\setup.py", line 989, in
```

setup(
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 670, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 136, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1229, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\MarosPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ehd7ptp\pillow_96d0524dfca7421cb23061be6a1a17a3\setup.py", line 804, in 
build_extensions
          raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
     
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "", line 2, in 
        File "", line 34, in 
        File "C:\Users\MarosPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ehd7ptp\pillow_96d0524dfca7421cb23061be6a1a17a3\setup.py", line 1009, in 
          raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
     
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
     
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
     
     
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Pillow

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: You need [these libraries](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-from-source), including `zlib`.

Comment: You're on windows, so installing the libraries is probably a hell. You may try precompiled [wheel](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files), just grab proper wheel for your python and arch and `pip install` it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.